# Postgresql vs Oracle for maintaing GIS data

Tags: postgis

We currently maintaining GIS data using oracle and ArcSDE. However, we want to explore better and cheaper alternatives. We came across using postgresql for maintaining gis database. Our business requires linear referencing and versioning capabilities. Also need to have topology and featuredatasets.

I am new to Postgresql. So, I do not know any thing about its performance and stability. Can you guys share your experience with respect to postgresql performance and stability in comparision with oracle. I want data to be safe and secure without any crashes.

We use ArcGIS products. We are also exploring using PostGIS and/or ArcSDE to manage data in postgresql. Since working with spatial data involves various software products I am also concerned about software updates and how it effects database maintainence.

I greatly appreciate if you could share your expertise and knowlege on this subject. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The performance and stability of PostgreSQL is definitely comparable with ORA.

The PostGIS extension is the most mature geospatial extension you can get from any free and open source (FOSS) database management systems regarding stability, performance and functionality.

PostGIS (or any other FOSS databas I know) though don't support versioning out of the box. You have to implement these yourself.

I assume you know that you can use ArcGIS with PostgreSQL using "PostGIS option" which means, that you loose versioning (AFAIK) but gain openess to (FOSS) tools wich can read PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last paragraph. What is FOSS tools? What are its benefits? I also need to maintain raster data. I learnt somewhere that it only possible with ArcGIS+ArcSDE+Postgresql. Is it true? If I need to implement versioning by myself means that I have to implement the sound logic to handle historic data and multi-user editing environement. Isn't it a difficult task. Do we have existing tools to do this?

Comment: It seams analysing software products that suites to business needs is not an easy task. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres is an ArcSDE supported DBMS.  This means the same geodatabase functionality(verisoning, complex objects, replication, etc.) available to Oracle or Sql Server is available to Postgres.  ArcGIS/SDE data can be stored in PG's native geometry type as well as facilitate Esri's St_Geometry and SDE binary format.  This is the same with all ArcSDE supported DBMS' now from 10.0 and later.  Postgres can keep up and at times out perform it's well established rivals.  Oh yeah, and PG is free.

Another secret is ArcSDE is no longer needed to view and edit DBMS spatial data in ArcGIS.  In fact spatial data isn't even needed anymore.  Everything is included in your ArcGIS installation at version 10.1.  Licensing is still a sore spot for some but the costs do come down and the software has been streamlined.

That said, PostgreSQL is very stable, can handle large data(physical and logical) and comes with great administration tools and documentation.  Did I mention Postgres is completely free?