# Postgres Version

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have been asked to develop my new application with Postgres 10.0. Before this, I have been developing applications with MsSql and was quite easy even. I searched for the Version 10.0 but didn't find any downloadable link. The latest version that i came across was Postgres 9.2 and 9.3 beta

Can anyone help me to find the right version. I had read few posts on Stackoverflow such as this one [Postgres 10.0 -Arcgis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236573/postgresql-vs-oracle-for-maintaing-gis-data/16976964#16976964) but don't know Arcgis is postgres database or is it the other DB engine same as Postgres and SQL Server.

**What i want is to know whether Postgres version 10.0 ( free or paid) is available or not?**

Comment: No. There is no Postgres 10.0 version. The next one will be 9.3 (currently in beta). Given the versioning schedule, I doubt there will be one in the 3-4 years (pure speculation!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no PostGre - there is PostgreSQL which is also sometimes called Postgres.

There is no version 10. The current version is 9.2.4 with 9.3 being the next version planned (due some time in 2013).

ArcSDE/Arcgis seems to be a GIS system that can work on top of PostgreSQL.

Comment: 9.4 *might* land up being called 10.0, but that's far from certain yet.